# A datepicker that fills a jquery filter-field in a list when pressed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

As the title says, I need help with getting the date from a datepicker to filter a list of events.

What I got so far:

I have a datepicker and a list with events. I would like to filter the list with the date picked in the datepicker when I press the date. However I cant find the correct way to call the filter-field of the list so I can accomplish this.

Here is the code for the datepicker, and when I press a date in the datepicker I get an alert as the comment says below, and this is also where I would like the input into the filter-box should happen:

```
$("#datepick").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    //This only marks the dates where there are events.
    var result = [true, '', null];
    var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
        return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
    });

    if (matching.length) {
        result = [true, 'highlight', null];
    }
    return result;
},
onSelect: function(dateText) {
    //This is what happens when you click a date.
    var date,
        selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
        i = 0,
        event = null;
    //An alert just to make sure it works up to this point. Here the list should be filtered.
    alert(selectedDate);    

}
```

});

And then we have the html which looks like this:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <div name="datepick" id="datepick"></div>
            <br />
        </div>      
    </form>

    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="mylist" name="mylist" >

            <li name="search" id="search" data-filtertext="Surfa på internet Mellangård Markaryd 2017-03-09 (arrangör)"><a href="addaktivitet.asp?id=2244" data-ajax="false">
            <h3>Surfa på internet</h3>
            <p><strong>Ort: Markaryd</strong></p>
            <p>Arrangör: 1</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>Datum: 2017-03-09
                                    <br />Tider: 13.30 - 16.00 </strong></p>
        </a></li>

            <li name="search" id="search" data-filtertext="Bingo Stig Inn Strömsnäsbruk 2017-03-09 (arrangör)"><a href="addaktivitet.asp?id=2252" data-ajax="false">
            <h3>Bingo</h3>
            <p><strong>Ort: Strömsnäsbruk</strong></p>
            <p>Arrangör: 1</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>Datum: 2017-03-09
                                    <br />Tider: 13.30 - 16.00 </strong></p>
        </a></li>

            <li name="search" id="search" data-filtertext="Filmafton Mellangård Markaryd 2017-03-13 (arrangör)"><a href="addaktivitet.asp?id=2245" data-ajax="false">
            <h3>Filmafton</h3>
            <p><strong>Ort: Markaryd</strong></p>
            <p>Arrangör: 1</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>Datum: 2017-03-13
                                    <br />Tider: 16.00 - 19.30 </strong></p>
        </a></li><!-- and so on...--></ul>
```

If it is possible to filter the list without the filter-box that is ok aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to keep both filters separated, so you will be allowed to filter by date and by free-text simultaneously.

One advantage of this approach is that you can separate the localized date visualization from the standard date format which you are using to store the information in your database.

In my proposal below, to implement such a multiple filter, i have defined a custom data-attribute which will contain just only the date of the event - this is however, not strictly necessary - finally, i'm combining both search criteria in the filter callback of the filterable widget:

```js
var dateFilter = "", dateFilterPlaceholder = "Choose a date";

function clearDateFilter(){
  dateFilter = "";
  $("#dp-button").text(dateFilterPlaceholder);
  $("#mylist").filterable("refresh");
}

function matchOrDate(idx, searchValue){
  var ret = false;
  if(dateFilter !== "") {
    var filtdate = $(this).data("datefilter") || "";
    if ((filtdate != dateFilter)) {
     ret = true; //filter this one out
    }
  }
  if (searchValue && searchValue.length > 0) {
      searchValue = searchValue.toLowerCase();
      var filttext = $(this).data("filtertext").toLowerCase() || "";
      if (filttext.indexOf(searchValue) < 0) {
          ret = true; //filter this one out
      }      
  }    
  return ret;
}

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-one", function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
      var d = date.getDate(), m = date.getMonth() + 1, y = date.getFullYear();
      dateFilter = "" + y + "-" + (m > 9 ? m : "0" + m) + "-" + (d > 9 ? d : "0" + d);
      $("#dp-popup").popup("close");
      $("#dp-button").text(dateText);
      $("#mylist").filterable("refresh");
    }
  });
  $("#mylist").filterable("option", "filterCallback", matchOrDate);
});






/*
 * jQuery Mobile: jQuery UI Datepicker Monkey Patch
 * http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2014/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-for-jquery-mobile.html
 */
(function() {
  // use a jQuery Mobile icon on trigger button
  $.datepicker._triggerClass += " ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all";
  // replace jQuery UI CSS classes with jQuery Mobile CSS classes in the generated HTML
  $.datepicker._generateHTML_old = $.datepicker._generateHTML;
  $.datepicker._generateHTML = function(inst) {
    return $("<div></div>").html(this._generateHTML_old(inst))
      .find(".ui-datepicker-header").removeClass("ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix").addClass("ui-bar-inherit").end()
      .find(".ui-datepicker-prev").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-notext").end()
      .find(".ui-datepicker-next").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-notext").end()
      .find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e, .ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w").replaceWith(function() {
        return this.childNodes;
      }).end()
      .find("span.ui-state-default").removeClass("ui-state-default").addClass("ui-btn").end()
      .find("a.ui-state-default.ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-priority-secondary ui-state-active").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-active").end()
      .find("a.ui-state-default").removeClass("ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-priority-secondary").addClass("ui-btn").end()
      .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane").removeClass("ui-widget-content").end()
      .find(".ui-datepicker-current").removeClass("ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini").end()
      .find(".ui-datepicker-close").removeClass("ui-state-default ui-priority-primary").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini").end()
      .html();
  };
  // replace jQuery UI CSS classes with jQuery Mobile CSS classes on the datepicker div, unbind mouseover and mouseout events on the datepicker div
  $.datepicker._newInst_old = $.datepicker._newInst;
  $.datepicker._newInst = function(target, inline) {
    var inst = this._newInst_old(target, inline);
    if (inst.dpDiv.hasClass("ui-widget")) {
      inst.dpDiv.removeClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix").addClass(inline ? "ui-content" : "ui-content ui-overlay-shadow ui-body-a").unbind("mouseover mouseout");
    }
    return inst;
  };
})();
```

```css
/*
 * jQuery Mobile: jQuery UI Datepicker Monkey Patch
 * http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2014/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-for-jquery-mobile.html
 */

.ui-datepicker {
  display: none;
}


/* set height and left/right margin to accomodate prev/next icons */

.ui-datepicker-header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.3125em 2.0625em;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  text-align: center;
}

.ui-datepicker-header .ui-btn {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}


/* fixed width layout for calendar; cells are fixed width */

.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  line-height: 2;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-btn {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.ui-datepicker-today .ui-btn {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-days-cell-over .ui-btn {
  border-color: inherit !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-buttonpane .ui-btn {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.ui-datepicker-buttonpane .ui-btn:last-child {
  float: right;
}


/* class that can be added to datepicker <input> element's wrapper; makes room for trigger button */

.dp-input-button-wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2.5em;
}

.dp-input-button-wrap .ui-btn {
  top: 0.1875em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-one" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Filter events</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="ui-grid-a">
          <div class="ui-block-a"><a id="dp-button" href="#dp-popup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-calendar ui-btn-icon-left ui-mini" data-transition="pop">Choose date</a></div>
          <div class="ui-block-b"><a id="clear-date-button" href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-mini" onclick="clearDateFilter(); return false" rel="external">Clear date filter</a></div>
      </div>
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="mylist" name="mylist" >
        <li data-filtertext="Surfa på internet Mellangård Markaryd (arrangör)" data-datefilter="2017-03-09">
          <a href="addaktivitet.asp?id=2244" data-ajax="false">
          <h3>Surfa på internet</h3>
          <p><strong>Ort: Markaryd</strong></p>
          <p>Arrangör: 1</p>
          <p class="ui-li-aside">
            <strong>Datum: 2017-03-09<br>Tider: 13.30 - 16.00</strong>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-filtertext="Bingo Stig Inn Strömsnäsbruk (arrangör)" data-datefilter="2017-03-09">
        <a href="addaktivitet.asp?id=2252" data-ajax="false">
          <h3>Bingo</h3>
          <p><strong>Ort: Strömsnäsbruk</strong></p>
          <p>Arrangör: 1</p>
          <p class="ui-li-aside">
            <strong>Datum: 2017-03-09<br>Tider: 13.30 - 16.00</strong>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-filtertext="Filmafton Mellangård Markaryd (arrangör)" data-datefilter="2017-03-13">
        <a href="addaktivitet.asp?id=2245" data-ajax="false">
          <h3>Filmafton</h3>
          <p><strong>Ort: Markaryd</strong></p>
          <p>Arrangör: 1</p>
          <p class="ui-li-aside">
            <strong>Datum: 2017-03-13<br>Tider: 16.00 - 19.30</strong>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="dp-popup" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
      <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Credits:

about the datepicker: i'm using in my example the jQuery UI datepicker restyled by [Salman Arshad](http://salman-w.blogspot.it/2014/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-for-jquery-mobile.html) simply because i like it, feel free to use any plugin you want, or style by yourself a [custom jQuery-UI download](http://jqueryui.com/download/), it doesn't matter.

The mutiple filter is an idea of the great [ezanker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098622/ezanker) from here: [JQuery Mobile filterable listview with multiple filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412024/jquery-mobile-filterable-listview-with-multiple-filters).

Please, a note *aside*: you should provide in your markup unique identifier for elements, list items and so on - which you need - You should pay attention to this point even more if you create your list items dynamically, otherwise nothing will work.